# menu_alter did not work

Tags: 7, routes

I try to use **menu_alter** for changing **Delete option** in access callback. I clear cache many times but it still not working.
I also tried some solution in this site but still got nothing. Please help me to solve this one.

```
function manage_child_menu_alter(&$items) {
   $items['comment/%/delete']['access callback'] = 'manage_child_comment_delete_access';
   $items['comment/%/delete']['access arguments'] = array(1);
   dpm($items);
}
```

Drupal Commons 3.28

Thanks.

Comment: Try clear cache `admin/config/development/performance`

Comment: I did it many times but not working. When I used update.php, it worked for once time only.

Comment: @NhãPhạm Is your `dsm()` shows the correct items?

Comment: Yes, it does. BTW, I found another solution to make it work. In ajax_comment, it had ajax delete menu, i simply attached it in to comment views alter and it worked. Thx guy.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common problem. What's your module weight? You can find the value in the table `system`. Try to change it to something more "*heavier*".

```
update DATABASE_NAME.system set weight = '99' WHERE name = "MODULE_NAME";
```

Standard approach hot to set a modude weight is to declare it in `MODULE_NAME.install` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_enable()
 */
function MODULE_NAME_enable() {
    db_update('system')
    ->fields(array('weight' => 99))
    ->condition('type', 'module')
    ->condition('name', 'MODULE_NAME')
    ->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thx Jasom, found solution for it. :)